# Unity make a curved line with existing points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I found the following class, which takes in a Vector3 array of points and returns a Vector3 array of new points to make a curve. You can see the result in the following screenshot, where the cubes are the original points, and the blue line is the result of the class.

[image: Curve]

What I would like to achieve are curved lines, but have the lines connected to the cubes just like the first and last cube for a result like this (blue points = original points; orange points = new points):

[image: Final Curve]

```
public class Curver : MonoBehaviour{
    //arrayToCurve is original Vector3 array, smoothness is the number of interpolations. 
    public static Vector3[] MakeSmoothCurve(Vector3[] arrayToCurve, float smoothness){
        List<Vector3> points;
        List<Vector3> curvedPoints;
        int pointsLength = 0;
        int curvedLength = 0;

        if(smoothness < 1.0f) smoothness = 1.0f;

        pointsLength = arrayToCurve.Length;

        curvedLength = (pointsLength*Mathf.RoundToInt(smoothness))-1;
        curvedPoints = new List<Vector3>(curvedLength);

        float t = 0.0f;
        for(int pointInTimeOnCurve = 0;pointInTimeOnCurve < curvedLength+1;pointInTimeOnCurve++){
            t = Mathf.InverseLerp(0,curvedLength,pointInTimeOnCurve);

            points = new List<Vector3>(arrayToCurve);

            for(int j = pointsLength-1; j > 0; j--){
                for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){
                    points[i] = (1-t)*points[i] + t*points[i+1];
                }
            }

            curvedPoints.Add(points[0]);
        }
        return(curvedPoints.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Here is how I am using the class:

```
void OnDrawGizmos(){
    Vector3[] points = Curver.MakeSmoothCurve(toVector3Array(wayPoints), 10f);
    bool ptset = false;
    Vector3 lastpt = Vector3.zero;
    for(int j = 0; j < points.Length; j++){
        Vector3 wayPoint = points[j];
        if(ptset){
            Gizmos.color = new Color(0, 0, 1, 0.5f);
            Gizmos.DrawLine(lastpt, wayPoint);
        }
        lastpt = wayPoint;
        ptset = true;
    }
    if(isCircular){
        Gizmos.DrawLine(lastpt, wayPoints[0].position);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cg_Programming/Unity/Hermite_Curves

Comment: That looks like a great wiki article! I will have a look at it, thanks for the post.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without tangents?

Comment: Since these points are generated by the player, do you have any suggestion on how I can generate a tangent point based on the location of point A and point B?